# How to fix dimensional error in Theano v0.8 tutorial code

Tags: python, theano

I'm following the [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html) in the v0.8 release of Theano.

It includes an example of creating & training a logistical regression as shown below:

```
rng = np.random 
N = 400 # training sample size
feats = 784 # number of input vars

D = (rng.randn(N, feats), rng.randint(size=N, low=0, high=2)) # generate a dataset

training_steps = 10000

x, y = T.matrix('x'), T.matrix('y')

w = theano.shared(rng.randn(feats), name='w') # init a weight vector randomly
b = theano.shared(0., name='b') # init bias variable
                                # both w and b are 'shared'

print "logistic regression: initial model:"
print w.get_value()
print b.get_value()

                                                # build expression graph
p_1 = 1/(1+T.exp(-T.dot(x,w)-b))                # Probability that target = 1
prediction = p_1 > 0.5                          # prediction threshold
xent = -y * T.log(p_1) - (1-y) * T.log(1-p_1)   # Cross-entropy loss function
cost = xent.mean() + 0.01 * (w ** 2).sum()      # The cost to minimize
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w, b])                   # Cost gradient = func(w,b)

train = theano.function(                        # compile training function
    inputs=[x,y],
    outputs=[prediction, xent],
    updates=((w, w - 0.1 * gw), (b, b - 0.1 * gb)))

predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=prediction)

for i in range(training_steps):                 # do the training
    pred, err = train(D[0], D[1])
```

Theano is throwing the following error:

> TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   "./tut.py:206"  at index 1(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions:
>   expected 2, got 1 with shape (400,).')

I'm reasonably certain the fix is simple (due to my newb status at Theano), and perhaps involves a reshape step. The tutorial doesn't have a good hint. Suggestions?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?
This one: pred, err = train(D[0], D[1]) ?

Comment: The tutorial you referred uses T.vector for 'y' but you are using T.matrix; labels (generally) are always vector (at-least for classification problems).

Comment: I overlooked the T.vector issue for the y labels variable. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to reshape `D[1]` before you use it in the theano function, maybe something like this (I haven't try it, tell me if it doesn't work):

```
pred, err = train(D[0], np.reshape(D[1],(400,1))
```

the error happen because you initialize `D[1]` in one dimensional array using `rng.randint(size=N, low=0, high=2)` but it's pass to matrix (two dimensional) variable `y`

or

the other simple solution is by using vector instead of matrix for variable `y`:

```
y = T.vector("y")
```

Comment: I overlooked the vector-vs-matrix issue for variable y. Thank you!